# iOS開発 のmediapicker(_ didPickMediaItems) を使用してアルバム情報を取得する方法

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift4

現在、music playerの開発に取り組んでいるのですが
スワイプすると現在再生している曲が入っているアルバムの次の曲を再生するような仕組みを
実装しようとしています。

mediapicker(_ didPickMediaItems) で曲を選択し、再生するようにしているのですが
引数のmediaItemCollectionには選択した一曲だけの情報しか入っていないためか
skipToNextItem()を使っても上手く動きません。

mediapicker(_,didPickMediaItems)で曲を選択した後に
その曲のアルバム情報を取得し、その次の曲にスキップするにはどのような方法があるでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MPMediaPickerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/MPMediaPickerController)はあくまで **曲** を選ぶためのUIとなっています。
`allowsPickingMultipleItems` が `false` の場合、 `didPickMediaItems` で渡される MPMediaItemCollection の中身は **1曲のみ** となります。
その mediaItemCollection を再生しても当然、その1曲のみが再生され、次の曲がないのでスキップすることはできません。

曲ではなく、アルバムを再生したいのならば、選択された [MPMediaItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitem) の `albumPersistentID` を条件に、 [MPMediaQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaquery) を使って**アルバムに含まれるすべての曲**を選択して再生すればよいでしょう。そうすれば（次の曲があれば）スキップもできるはずです。

**追記**

[MPMediaQuery.albums()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaquery/1621780-albums) に [MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitempropertyalbumpersistentid) をキーに指定した [MPMediaPropertyPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaitempropertyalbumpersistentid) を[条件に追加](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaquery/1621773-addfilterpredicate)して検索してみてください。

参考) [Using Filters to Create Specialized Queries](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/using_filters_to_create_specialized_queries)

Comment: 回答頂き、ありがとうございました。

nowPlayingItem の albumPersistentID を取得することは出来たのですが
そこから、albumPersistentIDはどのように利用するのかがよく分かりません。

色々、調べて見たのですが中々、有益な情報を見つけられなかったので
教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: 回答に追記しました。参考にしてみてください。